# When were javascript: URLs (pseudo-protocol) introduced into the HTML standard?

Tags: javascript, html, uri, specifications

The `javascript:` in URLs has from my reading on the internet been around for a very long time while not being an actual standard. The protocol is currently [part of the HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#javascript-protocol). When was this introduced into the HTML spec? I did a cursory search of the HTML4 standard and did not find it. I also found this [IETF draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hoehrmann-javascript-scheme) from 2010 proposing the resource identifier scheme.

Comment: I think you'll have to search the version history of the WHATWG spec, to see when that section was added.

Comment: Is there any way to search version history? Now that the HTML spec is a "living standard"

Comment: There's a github repo https://github.com/whatwg/html but I'm not sure how to search for this. The files have `.wattsi` extensions and I don't know how to view them. I found branches and issues mentioning JS URLs back in 2015. So they were added between the IETF draft in 2010 and these issues in 2015.

Comment: Why does the date matter? If it's just curiosity, you could try asking in [retrocomputing.se].

Comment: I don't think something that dates from 2010-2015 counts for retrocomputing

Comment: I know, but it tends to be the place to ask about history of things like this. I don't see how it's a programming question. Unless you need to know whether a particular old browser version will support it.

Comment: 10 years is practically an eon in computing.

Comment: It is a question about a programming language specification, so it on-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Ian Hickson added the "Javascript Protocol" section to the spec (basically just to indicate an intent to define it) on [Thu, 25 Jan 2007 20:12:17 +0000](https://searchfox.org/whatwg-html/rev/f2b895a09a2d32e6d1805d68113c62ca6a2847ae/source#16555)

(Earlier versions do mention "javascript: URIs", but mostly in comments, questions, and things to be done.)

[The commit of Thu Mar 1 22:41:49 2007 +0000](https://searchfox.org/whatwg-html/rev/9369fd00/source#18473) ("behold: the javascript: URI") is the first to provide detailed semantics, although it relies on an external "JSURI" reference.

[The commit of Fri Nov 15 15:56:16 2013 +0000](https://searchfox.org/whatwg-html/rev/d52ebc24/source#74171) ("Move javascript: processing entirely into HTML") is the first that doesn't need the "JSURI" reference.